# Cannot find some functions in Python API in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to convert a model from tensorflow to onnx. The process to do this is like following.

1. Save a `graph_def` and a `ckpt` for weights in tensorflow.
2. Inspect a `graph_def` whether it's structure is valid and give us what the inputs and outputs are.
3. Freeze both of them together into `frozen tensorflow graph`.
4. Convert that graph to onnx model.

The problem is in step 2. To inspect the graph definition, I tried to invoke summarize_graph in [Graph Transform Tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/v1.12.0/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms). But, it wasn't work properly. Next, i found documentation for Graph Transform Tool. According to the documentation they use `bazel` that is a tool to build and test like `maven`. It means that I cannot use this function in a tensorflow installed from pip package manager? Only way to use this function is to install a tensorflow from source and build with `bazel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be perfectly able to use these features installing TensorFlow from pip. Bazel is used to manage build procedures, you don't need It unless you want to compile TensorFlow from source by yourself.

Try to remove It and reinstall from pip paying attention to choose the right Python setup in case you have multiple Python distributions on your machine.